# Dart: Using observable with multiple getter/setter(s)

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

for my Polymer application I need one observable in two different flavors, for example as an integer-value and and string-value. I use getters and setters to encapsulate the state and internal representation. By doing this I have to implement **notifyPropertyChange** for every observable in every setter, which leads to much errorprone plumbing code. For example
I need two times to **notifyPropertyChange**-Statements for two flavors, if I have to use
4 flavors, I have to use 4*4 = 16 **notifyPropertyChange**-Statements. I have modified the click-counter example to illustrate this:

```dart
@CustomTag('click-counter')
class ClickCounter extends PolymerElement {
  int _count;
  @observable int get count => _count;
  @observable set count(int val) {
    notifyPropertyChange(#count,_count,val);
    _count = notifyPropertyChange(#strcount,_count,val);}

  @observable String get strcount { 
    print("TOSTRING "+_count.toString()); 
    return _count.toString();}

  @observable set strcount(String val) { 
    notifyPropertyChange(#strcount,_count,int.parse(val));
    _count = notifyPropertyChange(#count,_count,int.parse(val));}

  ClickCounter.created() : super.created() {
  }

  void increment() {
    count++;
  }
}
```

Is there a better way to implement this without so much **notifyPropertyChange**-Statements?

Regards

Markus

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested it, but it should work and I think its notable less code if you have more such properties.

```dart
@CustomTag('click-counter')
class ClickCounter extends PolymerElement {
  int _count;
  @observable int get count => _count;
  set count(int val) { 
    notifyPropertyChange(#count,_count,val);
    notifyPropertyChange(#strcount, _count.toString(), val.toString());
    _count = val;

  @observable String get strcount { 
    // print("TOSTRING "+_count.toString()); 
    return _count.toString();}

  set strcount(String val) { 
    count = int.parse(val); // set the new value using the setter not the field to fire property change
  }

  ClickCounter.created() : super.created();

  void increment() {
    count++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This works! So I have just one notifyPropertyChange per observable symbol.

Answer (score 1):

In case the `count` property doesn't need to be private — something to consider according to the [Dart style guide](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/style-guide/#prefer-using-a-public-final-field-instead-of-a-private-field-with-a-public-getter) — a sweet option would be available for this kind of situation.

```dart
class ClickCounter extends PolymerElement {
    @observable int count;
    ...
    void countChanged(oldValue) {
        // do something...
    }
}
```

Changes occurred to observable properties is automatically passed on method named as `<property_name>Changed` where property_name refers to the property to spy on.

Hope this help bring more fun to writing Polymer components.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this applies to you but I had the same problem. In my case though I could solve it with just the one property and a filter.

*dart class*

```
int count;

int asInt(...) // can't remember details of filters
```

*html*

```
<input type="text">{{count | asInt}}<input>
```

Apologies for the incorrectness of the code. I'm on my phone and don't have time to search the code. Hopefully you get the idea

Cheers
Anders