# Dynamically bind (or format) two @observable variables to a third @observable variable

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

Here's something I thought might be a bit easier. Despite the specifics of the question, I'm interested in any method that will let me have a third form field auto-updated based on the content of two other fields with Polymer.dart.

Something like this, where the "[ ]" represent form fields.

> Name:      [given name]  [family name]
>
> Full name: [family_name, given_name]

So for example; if someone enters "**John**" and "**Smith**" in the first two fields.  Then the "full name" line shows: [**Smith**, **John**], when either of the fields are updated.

I've based the following example on the classes and mark-up from the form [**Dart Polymer**](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/forms/) tutorial

- [Get Input from a Form](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/forms/) tutorial

For a form like this ...

```dart
  <polymer-element name="reference-form" extends="form" >
    <template>
      <style> ... </style>
      <div id="slambookform"  >
        <div class="entry">
          <label>Author:</label>
          <input type="text" value="{{theData['authorGivenName']}}" >
          <input type="text" value="{{theData['authorFamilyName']}}">
        </div>
          :
        <div class="entry">
          <label>Full name:</label>
          <input disabled type="text" value="{{fullName}}" >
        </div>
          :
      </div>
    <template>
  </polymer-element>
```

My initial attempt to make this happen was a function like:

```dart
@observable
String fullName(){

    return theData['authorFamilyName'] +', '+ theData['authorGivenName'];

}
```

Which doesn't work.  When I make 'fullName' to an @observable variable and update it with a button the form is updates as required.  Hence my question, can I bind a third field to two (or more) others?

I think I will need some kind of event handler.  For two fields, formatting on a change even is simple enough.  I want to format several fields in the ultimate case, not just two fields.

While on this topic, is there a hook in dart-polymer or dart to supply a future or call-back?  In my example, something like: '*after-change*'.  Just thinking out loud, something like that would be good.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22788028, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21941265

Answer (score 2):

Along those lines (caution - code is not tested)

```dart
 <polymer-element name="reference-form" extends="form" >
    <template>
      <style> ... </style>
      <div id="slambookform"  >
        <div class="entry">
          <label>Author:</label>
          <input type="text" value="{{authorGivenName}}" >
          <input type="text" value="{{authorFamilyName}}">
        </div>
          :
        <div class="entry">
          <label>Full name:</label>
          <input disabled type="text" value="{{fullName}}" >
        </div>
          :
      </div>
    <template>
  </polymer-element>
```

class reference_form.dart

```dart
String _authorGivenName;
@observable get authorGivenName => _authorGivenName;
set authorGivenName(String val) {
  _authorGivenName = val; 
  notifyPropertyChange(#fullName, '${_authorGivenName} ${_authorFamilyName}', 
    '${val} ${_authorFamilyName}');
}

String _authorFamilyName;
@observable get authorFamilyName => _authorFamilyName;
set authorFamilyName(String val) {
  _authorFamilyName = val; 
  notifyPropertyChange(#fullName, '${_authorGivenName} ${_authorFamilyName}',
    '${_autorGivenName} ${val}');
}

@observable
String get fullName => '${_authorGivenName} ${_authorFamilyName}';
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer Günter; the example as posted didn't quite work.  I've posted a minimal version below to show how I made changes to demonstrate _proof of concept_.

Comment: I see, using the return value of notifyPropertyChange is not appropriate here. 'Thanks' in comment is nice but upvote is usually preferred in StackOverflow.

Comment: Done.  I eschew politics where ever possible.

Comment: Do you have a chat room on StackOverflow?  It doesn't seem appropriate to clutter the QnA space with chit-chat.

Comment: I just created one named `Dart`

Answer (score 2):

I have a workaround for this problem, standing on the shoulders of Günter Zöchbauer (comment above).  My objective is to "***bind***" one field value to two in a read-only fashion. We are not quite there yet, however the pathway is educational in its own right.

### Observer method

This solution is kind of a workaround for the objective I set myself.  I've made some annotations on this code to explain what I saw, or why I think is happening.

The intention is for fullName to show both names in the form:

- familyName, givenName; e.g.
- ***Smith, John***

**reference-form**.html:

```dart
<polymer-element name="reference-form" extends="form" >
    <template>
      <style> ... </style>
      <div id="slambookform"  >
        <div class="entry">
          <label>Author:</label>
          <input type="text" value="{{theData['givenName']}}" >
          <input type="text" value="{{familyName}}">
        </div>
          :
        <div class="entry">
          <label>Full name:</label>
          <input disabled type="text" value="{{fullName}}" >
        </div>
          :
      </div>
    <template>
  </polymer-element>
```

The code for the form properties, the things Polymer-dart binds to the HTML with the moustache syntax, "{{***fullName***}}".  To keep things simple, I used just one '*notifier*' field and this updates the **fullName** field from both *familyName* and *givenName*.

**reference_form**.dart:

```dart
  //---- testing ----

  String _familyName;                        // (1) 
  @observable                                // (2)
  String get familyName => _familyName;      // (3)
  void   set familyName( String nam ){       // (4)
      _familyName = nam; 
      fullName    = notifyPropertyChange(    // (5)
                        #fullName, 
                        "${fullName}", 
                        "${nam}, ${theData['givenName']}" );
  }

  @observable
  String fullName;                           // (6)

  //---- end: testing ----
```

The private member, "**_familyName**", is a shadow for the public **familyName** property used in the template (snippet above).

1. Shadow (private) member, "***_familyName***", stores the data for the **familyName** pseudo property.
2. The next three lines declare an @observable property, **familyName**
3. [Get](http://www.dartlang.org/dart-tips/dart-tips-ep-10.html) **familyName**.  Simply echo the value for the shadow variable.
4. [Set](http://www.dartlang.org/dart-tips/dart-tips-ep-10.html) **familyName**.  Updates the shadow variable and the composite **fullName** property.

   - Note: the composit formatting could be *done* with two lines: 
      _familyName = nam; 
      fullName = nam; 
      ... But we want to see all changes propagated see (#5).
5. The ***notifyPropertyChange*()** method updated *all* observers of the **fullName** property.

   - Note: I didn't hack around inside Polymer itself; inside the Observable class, **fullName** doesn't has no observers with the code shown.
   - Until I saw this, I assumed that the Polymer binding to the HTML template was via an observer (watcher), it would seem not.  I may be mistaken.  In any case, the call to *notifyPropertyChange*() for the '#fullName' symbol didn't change the results for this test case.
6. fullName property bound to the Polymer form.

Basically the {{***fullName***}} value will be updated every time there's a change to the ***familyName*** pseudo property.

***Note on efficiency***:

- The familyName setter is called with every keystroke (observed while debugging).  I understand that, and suggest it is not always really the best solution.
- For me, I'd prefer to only call the setter when a user exits the field.  However when I used onblur, the trigger was a blur of the form, not the field.
- It seems that we might all benefit in terms of performance with a bit more insider information about these hooks, pathways and any options available to make things more efficient.

Comments and improvements welcome.  This example is a workaround for me, so its definitely a work in progress. ;-)

### Encapsulation method

I am evolving a solution closer to the original ambition and based on the '*observer method*' above.  This approach relies on the current, i.e. Dart v4, use of modules and libraries.  I'll show the working code first and explain interesting stuff with notes.

**reference_form**.dart:

```dart
import 'package:exportable/exportable.dart';                // [1]

class _Data                                                 // [2]
    extends Object with Exportable {                        // [3]

    @export String publishDate;                             // [4]
    @export String authorGivenName  = '(given)';
    @export String authorFamilyName = '(family)';
    @export String authorUrl        = ''; 

        //--- attributes ---

    String get fullName => "${authorFamilyName}, ${authorGivenName}"; // [5]
    void   set fullName( String nam ){                                // [6]
        //don't need this
    }

        //--- ctor ---

    _Data(){
        publishDate  = new DateTime.now().toString();                 // [7]
    }

} //_Data


@CustomTag('reference-form')
class SlamBookComponent extends FormElement with Polymer, Observable {

  SlamBookComponent.created() : super.created();

  //---- testing ----

  @observable
  _Data data = new _Data();                                           // [8]

      :

} //SlambookComponent
```

**Notes**:

1. Include [Exportable mixin](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/exportable) to convert to JSON.  I'm not exporting 'fullName' because it is just formatting at the moment.

   - Add **exportable** to your pubspec.yaml and '***Run Pub get***'.
2. The "_Data" class is private to the **reference_form**.dart module.  I did a bit of testing of the scope rules because I do not want the internal data structure to *leak*,  except for something catholic like JSON of course (small-c).
3. Bring-in the **Exportable** mixin.

   - I have tested [Exportable](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/exportable), it implements exactly what I thought I'd have to write myself.  Happy with this.
   - JSON is not a requirement of the original question; but I did want the (*eventual*) solution to be a *first class* artefact that can be serialized or saved is important in the majority of my use-cases.
   - This is a very good example of the facility to extend Dart quick and agile!
4. Use the **@export** modifier to identify fields specific to be interchanged as JSON.
5. Export the ***fullName*** attribute as a **String** (get).
6. There is no need for set operation.  However Dart apparently insists that a Set method matches '*get*'.

   - I am disappointed by this.  I much prefer the idea that I can have READ-ONLY properties and attributes, e.g. like [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby).
   - As tested, Dart SDK v1.4.0; fails when a matching ***setter*** is not implemented/declared(??).
7. Use a constructor to set initial values for Date data attribute.
8. Declares an opaque public property called "*data*", as an (*private*) _Data instance.

   - The data formatting of key fields is encapsulated in the private _Data declaration.
   - The [Exportable mixin](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/exportable) interface is used to map the private class to a ***public*** JSON result.

Point **#8** demonstrates a powerful aspect of [[image]dart](/questions/tagged/dart), to enable an opaque implementation of objects and yet, you can '*deliver*'/'*share*' details without specific internal details.

I have run this code and checked that the concepts work for hidden data (the **_Data** type) and opaque access and serialisation.  Also you can't accidentally look at internal private type (*accidentally*, although explicit hacks may be possible).  I don't apologise for accepting the C / C++ conscious responsibility paradigm -- I think this a the most powerful aspect of being a programmer; *WE* are *responsible* for effects/bugs stemming from the code we produce.  I recommend testing '*bits* of behaviour' in small mini-use-cases.

I put examples of the [polymer](/questions/tagged/polymer) markup; nothing surprising.  For me this approach is less verbose and a bit more Object Oriented than the original (early) Dart tutorial

**reference_form.html**

```dart
  <polymer-element name="reference-form" extends="form" >
    <template>
    <style> ... </style>
      <div id="slambookform"  >

        <div class="entry">
          <label>Author:</label>
          <input type="text" value="{{data.authorGivenName}}" >
          <input type="text" value="{{data.authorFamilyName}}">
        </div>
        <div class="entry">
          <label>Published:</label>
          <input type="date" value="{{data.publishDate}}">  
        </div>

      </div>
    </template>

    <script type="application/dart" src="reference_form.dart"> </script>
  </polymer-element>
```

In the **Polymer** mark-up can *know* (and has *visibility over*) internal field names.  ***Why?***

... Because the "**reference_form**.html" and "**reference_form**.dart" via Polymer-dart.  It is quite nice really; although it seems that the ".dart" and ".html" components are closely coupled like ASP.NET and C#/VN.NET as (also) *specified by convenience*(??).  I confess that's a completely different subject; there are things to resolve to keep things *[yar](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/yar)* (yachting term).

Anyway for me, I feel the approach begun with the encapsulation shamble above is better suited to my needs for a small utility.

---

Comment: Can you create a question for you onBlur problem?

Comment: I disagree regarding the comment to use the _*notifyPropertyChange*()_ return.  It is needed imho, to ensure that the fullName property is given the same value as any down-stream dependant observers.  It's a _data integrity_ issue.  In threaded code and message passing systems like Ruby, Smalltalk and MCS-s, bugs happen when an upstream element assumes the data passed-on will be the same-as the result.  In the message environment, you must never assume that. It's a hot-list item for 'message systems' (MCS) like MVC.  That said; yes you can _cheat_ with it on a small app like this use case.

Comment: Ok, but in my code the return value was assigned to the wrong field. It's the value for the change-notified field not the value of the backing field of the current setter.

Comment: @Günter ... Backing field comment.  I debugged that; it didn't work that way with Dart v1.4.   I added the more explicit, verbose setter syntax to unwrap any Dart stuff, but it wouldn't work.  That's when I went to [Dart tips - Getters/Setters](http://www.dartlang.org/dart-tips/dart-tips-ep-10.html) shown above.  Anyway the answer above is just a prototype.  I definitely want to find a way to bind elements because I want to _blend_ many fields in different ways.

Answer (score 1):

Polymer now supports this use case directly with `@ObserveProperty`

```dart
  @observable String authorGivenName = '';
  @observable String authorFamilyName = '';
  @observable String get fullName => '${authorGivenName} ${authorFamilyName}';

  @ObserveProperty('authorGivenName authorFamilyName')
  void updateFullName(old) {
    notifyPropertyChange(#fullName, old, fullName);
  }
```